# add rows to dataframe after multiply by column value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following datafame:

```
count   color   name
2       blue    mike
3       red     james   
1       orange  mark    
3       yellow  oscar
```

I want to take the count value and insert as many rows as the count value. The output should be:

```
count   color   name
2       blue    mike
2       blue    mike
3       red     james
3       red     james
3       red     james   
1       orange  mark    
3       yellow  oscar
3       yellow  oscar
3       yellow  oscar
```

I've tried to use the multiply function, but this is just multiplying the count column when I want to insert more rows. If someone could point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `reindex` and `repeat`

```
df = df.reindex(df.index.repeat(df['count']))
```